# updating placeholders of view page in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, placeholder

I have a controller that uses a GET method to receive an array of data. I have put each values in the array in to scopes. I want to update placeholders in my view with the values in the array. But all I get is a empty field.

**controller**

```
;
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', []).controller('questionEditCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {



            $scope.edit = function (id) {

                var edit_url = 'http://localhost/AwtCW2012002/api/restApiController/editQuestion.json?question_id=' + id;

                $http.get(edit_url)

                        .success(function (data) {

                            $scope.data1 = data;

                            $scope.data1.question = data.quizes[0].question;
                            $scope.data1.answer1 = data.quizes[0].answers[0];
                            $scope.data1.answer2 = data.quizes[0].answers[1];
                            $scope.data1.answer3 = data.quizes[0].answers[2];
                            $scope.data1.answer4 = data.quizes[0].answers[3];
                            $scope.data1.answer5 = data.quizes[0].answers[4];
                            //$scope.data.correctAnswer = data.quizes[0].correctAnswer;

                            console.log(data1.question);
                            console.log(data1.answer1);
                            console.log(data1.answer2);
                            console.log(data1.answer3);
                            console.log(data1.answer4);
                            console.log(data1.answer5);
                            //console.log(data.correctAnswer);


                        })
                        .error(function () {

                        })

            };


        }]);

})();
```

I'm trying to pass the values into my placeholders in the view as follows

**View**

```
<div class="container" >

    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name='quizAdd' ng-submit="submit(data)">



        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="question">Question:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="question" id="question" ng-model="data.question" placeholder="{{data1.question}}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

But all I get is a empty field.(in the log, it shows the value properly)

Comment: Placeholder is hidden when there is a value, and aren't they supposed to be same model? `ng-model="data.question" placeholder="{{data1.question}}"`

Comment: What does your data.question give you back? If it has any value, your placeholder is hidden.
Try setting

 $scope.data.question = "";

Comment: @OscarBout data.question gives nothing. and I tried $scope.data.question = '' . still not working

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly no they are supposed to be 2 different models. in placeholder I want some old values. when user enters new values it should go to data.question .

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but when using `ng-model`, your are binding `data.question` to your controller scope, but I don't see it in your controller code. Where is something like `$scope.data.question`?